# HTML image/video playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a set of images and videos. And I want to implement a player which can loop through all the images and videos.
As an example, 
A - image, B - video, C - image;
assets = [A, B, C];
I want a html player which loop through this array, first show A(image) for an interval[5s], then autoplay the B(video) and end of the video, shows C(image) for an interval(5s) and repeat the flow. I have tried something like below code. But this is not a solution for a video.

```js
var previewContainer = $(".previews-container");
var curIndex = 1;

appendMediaElement(loopAssets[0]); //initial 

setInterval(function() {
  if(curIndex >= loopAssets.length) {
     curIndex = 1;
  }

  appendMediaElement(loopAssets[curIndex]); //loopAssets array contains all the images and vidoes with meta data which is retrive from a ajax call

  curIndex++;
  
}, 5000);


function appendMediaElement(asset) {
    var mediaEl = "";
    if(asset.mediaType == "IMAGE") {
        mediaEl =  '<img id="lp-preview-image" src="' + asset.contentUrl + '">';
        previewContainer.html(mediaEl);
    } else if(asset.mediaType == "VIDEO") {
        mediaEl = "<video id='lp-preview-video' autoplay controls>";
        mediaEl += "<source src='"+ asset.contentUrl + "' type='" + asset.contentType + "'>";
        mediaEl += "</video>";
        previewContainer.html(mediaEl);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <div id="loop-preview">
    <div class="item previews-container" style="width: 700px; height: 450px">
      <!-- images/vidoes-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any better solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Yea give me a sec I'll post the answer

Comment: As a side comment: the first image/video will only be displayed when the page is loaded the first time and never again, because in the `setInterval` you are setting `curIndex` to 1 (instead of 0)

Comment: What do you mean by "_any better solution_"? A faster solution? a more efficient solution? a less-code solution?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I mean working solution :)  my solution is not working. because, I set an interval for 5s. but what if the video is  30s one. so need to go to next item after the video ends. if next item also a video, then need to play that full video and move to the next item.

Comment: so you want the images to be 5 seconds, but the videos to be displayed fully. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with what you mentioned on your comments:

- Images will be displayed for 5 seconds, and
- Videos will be displayed completely

before moving to the next media element.

Trying to change your code minimally, this is a list of things that could be done:

- Remove the `setInterval` (but keep the function that changes the media, rename it to something like `changeMedia`)
- At the end of the code when it is an image, add a `setTimeout` that calls the new function that you created (`changeMedia`) after 5 seconds.
- At the end of the code when it is a video, add a listener to the end of the video (`ended` event) in which you call the function that you created (`changeMedia`).

And that should be it. For my code, I assumed this is the data that you get from AJAX (it follows all the requirements from your original code, although it's possibly just a minified version of what you get):

```
var loopAssets = [
    { contentUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/", contentType: "image/jpg", mediaType:"IMAGE" },
    { contentUrl: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", contentType: "video/mp4", mediaType: "VIDEO"},
    { contentUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/", contentType: "image/jpg", mediaType:"IMAGE" }
];
```

So, here is a working demo  (see the comments in the places that I changed):

```js
var loopAssets = [
  { contentUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/", contentType: "image/jpg", mediaType:"IMAGE" },
  { contentUrl: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", contentType: "video/mp4", mediaType: "VIDEO"},
  { contentUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/", contentType: "image/jpg", mediaType:"IMAGE" }
];
var previewContainer = $(".previews-container");
var curIndex = 1;

appendMediaElement(loopAssets[0]);

// removed the setInterval but kept the function
function changeMedia() {

  if(curIndex >= loopAssets.length) {
    // modified this so it would display the first image/video when looping
    curIndex = 0;
  }

  appendMediaElement(loopAssets[curIndex]);

  curIndex++;

};


function appendMediaElement(asset) {
  var mediaEl = "";
  if(asset.mediaType == "IMAGE") {
    mediaEl =  '<img id="lp-preview-image" src="' + asset.contentUrl + '">';
    previewContainer.html(mediaEl);
    // image: go to the next media after 5 seconds
    setTimeout("changeMedia()", 5000);
  } else if(asset.mediaType == "VIDEO") {
    mediaEl = "<video id='lp-preview-video' autoplay controls>";
    mediaEl += "<source src='"+ asset.contentUrl + "' type='" + asset.contentType + "'>";
    mediaEl += "</video>";
    previewContainer.html(mediaEl);
    // video: go to the next media when the video ends
    document.getElementById("lp-preview-video").addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
      changeMedia();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <div id="loop-preview">
    <div class="item previews-container" style="width: 700px; height: 450px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I said, this is the simplest change to make your code work as you defined in your question and comments, to make it better/more efficient, you may want to look into doing other enhancements (for example: hide/show instead of create/delete elements).

Comment: Very descriptive answer. I did some modifications to fit with my code base and its working fine. Thank you very much @Alvaro

Comment: Although this works @Alvaro I can't believe you would even call my code a bad solution in comparison... I can point out so many different things your doing wrong, an example of just one would be your declaring HTML elements as strings and writing it into the innerHTML `previewContainer.html(mediaEl)` lol... this is not good programming and not efficient, nor does it even utilizing the DOM... Please! know what the hell your talking about before you down talk someones answer like you did mine, just so you can get points... smh....

Comment: @JordanDavis I didn't say my solution was optimal. In fact, I mention in my answer that it is the minimal changes to OP's code needed to make it work, and in the last paragraph I even mention that it can be improved in different ways. About your solution, I'll be happy to delete my comments if the answer is improved, but until then I will stand by them

Comment: I already updated my code... I personally don't care, my point I'm trying to make is don't criticize someone just so you get the answer right it's not constructive and brings confusion to the person were trying to help... and especially if you answer is worst then the person your criticizing...

Comment: I will check your new answer when I'm on a computer (right now I'm on mobile). And I'm sorry you think I did it with bad intentions. Feel free to downvote my answer and report my comments/solution to the admins or in meta if you think what I did was wrong. That's all I have to say.

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, chill down guys, I appreciate both answers and thank you very much for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LgLvejd2/3/)

**//CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}   
#media{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self:center;
}
#media>img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}   
</style>
<script>
var imgFormat = ["jpg","png"];
var content = [
"http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/space-wallpapers-9.jpg",
"http://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1694950/preview/stock-footage-operator-cleans-lens-of-professional-videocamera-and-on-background-scenery-are-prepared.mp4",   
"http://www.sciencesortof.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/218_space_beer.jpg",
"http://www.spirit1059.com/pics/Feeds/Articles/2015611/118317/Beach.jpg",
"http://ak7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3775625/preview/stock-footage-northern-lights-aurora-borealis-reflected-on-a-lake-timelapse-in-iceland.mp4"
];
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(document.readyState == "interactive"){mediaChange();}
}
function mediaChange(){
    var mediaBox = document.getElementById("media");
    setInterval(function(){
        var media = mediaBox.children[0];
        var key = content.indexOf(media.getAttribute("src"));
        if((key+1) == content.length){key = 0;}
        else{key += 1;}
        var format = content[key].substr(content[key].length - 3);
        changeMedia(mediaBox,media,key,format);
    }, 5000);
}
function changeMedia(mediaBox,media,key,format){
        if(imgFormat.indexOf(format) < 0){
            var ele = document.createElement("video");
            ele.setAttribute("autoplay", true);
        }
        else{var ele = document.createElement("img");}
        ele.setAttribute("src",content[key]);       
        mediaBox.replaceChild(ele,media);           
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="media">
    <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/space-wallpapers-9.jpg">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro As I mentioned in a comment block, loopAssets is an object array which contains images and videos with metadata. it is retrieved from an ajax call which is not in my code snippet. sorry about that.

Comment: First of all @AlvaroMontoro he never said AJAX, and what he listed was for three elements (img,vid,img) to loop.... your right I could make this a little more OOP by separating by `tagName` (video | img) but since there is ONLY two images, really didn't see the point... I'll update the code to show the minor OOP change...

Comment: I just mentioned an example with 3 media files. But there can be more in the loopAssets array as @AlvaroMontoro mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the delay had work all day... I updated the code for OOP, you can just `push` whatever ajax items you have into the array, the code will read the file format and adjust accordingly right now it filters (img|jpg) you can add whatever other formats you want to support... if it's not one of the filters (img|jpg) it will automatically assume `video` and generate for you.